# constant defined in super can't be used in subclass' super.init?

Tags: swift

I think I'm missing something blinding obvious here, but I have:

```
class ObjectSprite: SKSpriteNode {
  let kSpriteSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)
  weak var object: Game.Object?
}
```

and in my subclass:

```
class PlayerSprite : ObjectSprite {
 init(_ player: Game.Object) {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: SKColor.green, size: kSpriteSize)
    object = player
    name = "player"
  }
}
```

Swift complains `'self' used in property access 'kSpriteSize' before 'super.init' call`. But isn't that a constant? Why isn't it initialized at compile time?

Comment: Given that `size` is already a property of `SKSpriteNode`, there's no need to store `kSpriteSize` as a separate property. Just use the `size` property that you inherited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the `super` call using `self` to make the error message obvious:

```
super.init(texture: nil, color: SKColor.green, size: self.kSpriteSize)
```

As the error message is saying, you can't access properties on `self` before calling `super.init`.

You have a few options:

1. Declare `kSpriteSize` as a `static let` and refer to it as `ObjectSprite.kSpriteSize`.
2. Move `let kSpriteSize` to the root of the file, i.e. outside the class.

Comment: static it is! not ideal in this case, but working is a feature